# The confusion about the usage of word 'prove'

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence below, can I just add been before proven?

> In the past this process of transition has often proven difficult

In another sentence, do we have any particular meaning here when we use was to prove, could we use prove to be or has been proven?

> an experiment which was to prove a source of inspiration for many years to come.

Answer (score 2):

> "an experiment which **was to prove** a source of inspiration for many
>   years to come."
>
> "an experiment which **would prove to be** a source of inspiration for
>   many years to come."

Both of these examples sound great, and have exactly the same meaning. "Prove" here is a linking verb, definition #2 in [MacMilllan on-line](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/prove). The "proving" has been done by the natural effects of time, not by any conscious attempt at explicit "proof".

But with "has been proven", you are using the passive voice of "prove" as a transitive verb, definition #1 in the same dictionary.

> "an experiment which **has been proven** a source of inspiration for
>   many years to come."

This one sounds a little strange if you think about it. Because of the transitive verb, it carries the subtle (and some may say "overly picky") implication that someone has somehow constructed a real "proof" that the experiment in question will, in fact, be a future source of inspiration.

Comment: In think in the final example 'which has proven to be' is the way to say it - linking verb plus infinitive. Or you could even say 'has been proven to be' to keep it in the passive voice.

Comment: Yes to "which has proven to be" [with linking verb], but I don't think you want passive voice. Because passive voice implies transitive verb and an [unnamed] actor. That would indicate someone proving something [on purpose], not just the passage of time developing the validity of something.

Comment: I just suggested a passive version because your example was passive. I think the meaning of 'has been proven' and 'has been proven to be' are identical, except that the second version includes the required verb 'to be' referring to the experiment itself. It has to be there somewhere for the grammar, just as you can't say 'an experiment which *is* a source of inspiration' without 'is'. In other words 'to be' is actually the main verb in the sentence, regardless of which tense and voice is used.

Comment: "Proven", as a linking verb carries within it the idea of "to be". In the first example from the original question: "In the past this process of transition has often proven difficult", there is no "to be" because in "prove - definition #2" (linking verb) you don't need it. Compare other linking verbs: "It *seems* difficult." "That *sounds like* my husband."